# Building a self-iterating table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, datatables, iteration

In my code I take user inputs, save them and pass them to an API. I then need to output these user inputs to a table. Every time the user presses the button to submit their data, I need a new row of the new user inputs to be added.

I have read up on building tables in javascript, but obviously I am using IDS in my table in order to pass the variable, and am unsure of how to iterate a table that creates with user inputs and also has IDS for the element.

I have found a workaround through html below but it allows limited inputs and is extremely sloppy, I'm sure there is a better way for me to learn.

Many thanks!

Function:

```
function writeFName() {

var fNameGroup = document.querySelector('#fName_Input').value;
first_name = document.querySelector('#fName_Input').value;

localStorage.setItem('fName-group', fNameGroup);

var cfmF = confirm("Did you mean to enter: \n" + fNameGroup + '?');

if (cfmF) {
    console.log(fNameGroup);
    window.alert('Success!');

    first_name = localStorage.getItem('fName-group');

    document.querySelector("#firstname" + CSS.escape(x)).innerHTML = first_name;
    x++
} else {
    window.alert('Please Re-Enter First Name');
}
}


<div id="outputTable">
<table>
<tr>
<th> First Name </th>hg
<th> Last Name  </th>
<th> Email      </th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td id="firstname"></td>
<td id="lastname"></td>
<td id="email"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td id="firstname1"></td>
<td id="lastname1"></td>
<td id="email1"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td id="firstname2"></td>
<td id="lastname2"></td>
<td id="email"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: You didn't ask a specific question.

Comment: TLDR: How to create a new row of user input data whenever the user clicks a button

Answer (score 1):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/aL2u1wj9/ of dynamically adding new rows to table.

You can create elements via [document.createElement();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) then you need to add those element to the DOM using [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```
<table id="dynamicTable">
<tr>
<th> First Name </th>
<th> Last Name  </th>
<th> Email      </th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td id="firstname"></td>
<td id="lastname"></td>
<td id="email"></td>
</tr>
</table>


function appendToTable(firstName, lastName, emailAddress) {
   var table = document.getElementById("dynamicTable");

   var tr = document.createElement("tr");

   var firstNameTD = document.createElement("td");
   var lastNameTD =  document.createElement("td");
   var emailAddressTD =  document.createElement("td");

   table.appendChild(tr);

   tr.appendChild(firstNameTD);
   tr.appendChild(lastNameTD);
   tr.appendChild(emailAddressTD);

   firstNameTD.textContent = firstName;
   lastNameTD.textContent = lastName;
   emailAddressTD.textContent = emailAddress;
}

appendToTable("John", "Doe", "email 1 @ address");
appendToTable("Jane", "Doe", "email 2 @ address");
appendToTable("Another", "one", "email 3 @ address");
```

Comment: Ah so everytime the function is called, a new row is created, so no iteration is needed. Makes sense thanks man.

Comment: Everytime I run it I get the error. Cannot read property 'appendchild' of null. I have moved the script to the bottom of the page but still to no avail. I have pasted my code here https://codeshare.io/G6yN0k if you would be kind enough to have a look through it.

Comment: Delete your HTML code you used in your example in opening post and replace it with the one provided in my example. It failing because it can't find <table id="dynamicTable">

Comment: Still recieving the same error that it cannot append property 'appendchild' or null even after pasting your html code. Is it because the DOM has not finished loading?

Comment: Put the HTML at the top of the file and the javascript code anywhere after it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the working example of a table plugin which i made using jquery,css,and bootstrap.You can add multiple rows and edit the input fields.

https://codepen.io/yadu_krish/pen/GPgpwQ

```
code for adding Multiple rows on button click


$("#btnAdd").click(function(){ 
var html = '<tr><td><input class="name" type="text"/></td><td><input 
type="text" class="designation"/></td><td><select class="Department"><option 
selected >Please Select</option><option 
value="Development">Development</option><option 
value="Testing">Testing</option><option value="UI">UI</option><option 
value="3">Management</option></select></td><td><button class="btn- btn-link 
delete">Delete</button> <button class="btn- btn-link done">Done</button> </td> 
</tr>'
$('tbody').append(html); 
});
```